# NGINX: HTTP to HTTPS redirect not working

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, https, http

First time posting here. I've been searching on here for about two days to find a solution to my problem and nothing is working.

I know, there is a ton of posts about this same problem but none of the threads solutions I have came across, have worked so far. I am using NodeJS w/ Angular 5 on an Amazon EC2 instance.

Navigating to https://example.com works fine. The web page loads correctly. But, http://example.com gives me the "Welcome to nginx!" page.

Here is my nginx server config blocks:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name example.com

    server_tokens off;
    charset utf-8;
}

... SSL config stuff ...

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;

      proxy_set_header Host               $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Proxy "";
    }
}
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name example.com

      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

- Tried changing default_server to the port 80 block
- Tried using $server_name instead of $host on the redirect line
- Tried having the port 80 block on top of the port 443 block
- Checked for syntax errors in the config files (everything is fine)

Also checked for any conflicting files (none that I saw linked to nginx.conf).

```
curl -I http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 18 Jul 2018 04:18:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Tue, 31 Jan 2017 15:01:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5890a6b7-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

As you can see, when I curl http://example.com (not actually example.com), it returns a status of 200 rather than 301. Also, the "Network" tab in Firefox's developer tools, shows a status of 304.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `$server` instead of `$host`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Please refer below docs. might be helpful 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/best-way-to-configure-nginx-ssl-force-http-to-redirect-to-https-force-www-to-non-www-on-serverpilot-free-plan-by-using-nginx-configuration-file-only

Comment: I am not sure how or why, but I must be going crazy. I had $server_name instead of $host before I posted my config here but it wasn't working that way either. Now it somehow is. Regardless, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering this although it's been accepted because I think the answer is wrong.

I'm pasting your config below ***as-is***, with only a comment pointing to the wrongly placed (extra it seems) curly bracked closing the server block:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name example.com

    server_tokens off;
    charset utf-8;
}                                 <--------- CLOSED BLOCK WITH EXTRA BRACKET

... SSL config stuff ...

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;

      proxy_set_header Host               $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Proxy "";
    }
}
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name example.com

      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

The recommended way is to use the `$host` as you had it initially. The `$server_name` variable will be replaced by the virtualhost definition instead of the URL entered by the user. This could cause you problems if you are using server_alias for example. You can read the definition of each variable in the [official nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables). Here is a quote:

```
$server_name
    name of the server which accepted a request 

$host
    in this order of precedence: host name from the request line, or host name from the “Host” request header field, or the server name matching a request
```

So. I think your problem was the curly bracket, and not the variable. You should probably return to the $host and try again if it works.

ps. also remove the `proxy_http_version` line and the `proxy_set_header` with the empty "", they are not needed unless you have a very specific use-case.

Comment: There are use cases for both using `$host` and `$server_name`. If one has multiple virtual hosts, then `$host` can be used to implement the redirect for all virtual hosts. If there is only one virtual host and one wants to implement the redirect for only that host, then `$server_name` is better.

Comment: Not necessarily only with virtual hosts, $server_name could mess with redirects too, by overwriting the URL to the virtual host definition. Using instead   $host variable, you are respecting the user/browser input, as the “Host” header field of the request is tested against the server_name entries of the server blocks.

Comment: That extra bracket was an accident when I was pasting the config over. I tried $host and $server_name before I posted here (as I saw many different reasons from different threads on to use one or the other), i tried IPv6 port configs on both 80 and 443 before I posted as well. All i did was change $host back to $server_name and added the IPv6 port config only for port 80 this time and it worked. Not really understanding why it started working either.